# Return to Specific Activity in 2 different Condition when Back button Pressed Kotlin

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, flags, back-stack

Activity A,B,C,D .first path is A->C->D .when back button Pressed from D ,it will go like D->C->A. But My requirement is D->A.
in same App, I have another condition .second path is A->B->C->D .when back button pressed from D,it will happen like D->C->B->A.But My Requirement is D->A.
How to easily Accommodate both requirement in my App ?
but note that when click back from C then it should go to B.

Comment: `val intent = Intent(this, YourActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()`

Comment: i used anko . so     statrtActivity<YourActivity>()      how can i add intent flag with this code.

Comment: `startActivity(activity.intentFor<YourActivity>().doWhatever`

Comment: how can i add two flag after code startActivity(activity.intentFor<YourActivity>().Here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `onBackPressed()` in D like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

This will remove all activities between D and A from the stack and return to the existing instance of A.

NOTE: This is Java, not Kotlin, but you should be able to figure out how to Kotlinize the code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are two option

1 ) By On BackPress Kotlin:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
  val intent = Intent(this, A::class.java)
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
  startActivity(intent)
  finish()
}
```

2)By  Manifest.xml

What about adding in manifests file for related activity :

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

to the activity definition of B and C ? They will not be added to the backstack. Not sure if that is what you want.